# How to quickly find online help for SharePoint 2013 features?

Tags: 2013

I want to create custom documentation for new SharePoint Users in my company.

Example:
People had problems copying files from one library to another with the "send to" and "manage copies" commands in the FILES Ribbon.

I tried to find documentation of that feature online, but at least my search for *sharepoint 2013 file "manage copies"* found nothing helpful:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/results.aspx?qu=sharepoint+2013+file+%22manage+copies%22&ex=1&filter=1

Although I explicitly typed the name of the button "manage copies".

Is there an easy way to quickly find help for a certain feature?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. What I did was adding custom help to a site collection in the topics that were not properly covered. Here is how you can do it :

```
1.Create a new Site Collection Help library.
2.Create a new Help Collection Folder.
3.Create Categories for your help—that is, the headings for a table of contents.
4.Create and upload articles and media.
5.Add your Help article to your Help collection.
6.Display your new Help Collection in your site collection.
```

For a step by step guide, please click [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-foundation-help/add-custom-help-to-a-site-collection-HA101833141.aspx) .

Comment: thanks a lot! But for my special problem: how can I find the documentation online for a feature like the "send to" button?

Comment: in the upper right corner of SharePoint is a question mark, click on that. The help window will pop up. Search if there is help available there by using the name of the feature as search keyword.

Comment: I did that but I did not find the help concerning "send to" for example, as it is a widely used term :-( . For example, if I enter "manage copies", I only get 1 result "Create a multi-language website" .. not what I want :-(